# Why is this code printing a null string?

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to take a set of characters from a text file then store it in a string and print it. However when compile and run the file, it returns null.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadString
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

    ReadString read = new ReadString();
    System.out.println(read.readFileTxt());   //Prints the string content read from input stream

    }   

    public String readFileTxt() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            out.append(line);
            }

      //  reader.close();
    return line;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is what a debugger is for, it lets you answer these questions easily for yourself.

Comment: I run code using an editor and command line. This wasn't a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the last line (which is null because it caused the loop to exit) instead of `out.toString()`.

Comment: Does this count as a string itself? Would it be treated as one? Could I assign it as String stuff=out.toString()

Comment: I don't know what you mean. you've put each line of the file into the StringBuilder. So if you want the entire file as a string you should convert `out` to a string by calling `out.toString()` and then return it. @munchschair

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the last line read from the file. 
You want to return out.toString() instead.